Flashing screen on Ubuntu 24.04
I have a very frustrating problem.
video
When I use my Ubuntu 24.04 I sometimes have a flashing screen like in the attached video. I only see it when my mouse is somewhere in the lower part of the screen and it is sporadic (problems do not always occur when the mouse is on the bottom of the monitor). If it flashes and I move the mouse, it goes away.
I do not have this problem on Windows 11 and I remember not having this problem on Ubuntu 22.04. I tried to change the system on Pop_OS! 22.04, but the problem is still there.
Moreover the problem does not always occur. For example, I have never seen it while gaming.
How can I find out what the problem is?
I have switched to NVIDIA only in PRIME and the problem still occurs. I tried moving the lid of the laptop while it was flashing to see if maybe the connectors were to blame, but no. The problem was happening all the time. I wanted to try and capture the screen so I pressed the super button to run OBS. Pressing the button made the problem go away. When I pressed it again to return to the previous state, everything was fine.
Now I can use:
  Ubuntu 24.04
  Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic
  Windowing system: Wayland
  GNOME Version: 46
  Graphics: Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
  CPU: Intel Core i5-9300H × 8

Please clarify what is the exact OS and version you are running now?

More to the point in @David DE 's comment - which Ubuntu are you running?  That would be something like KUbuntu, XUbuntu, LUbuntu.  It's another way of asking what GUI you have.  Regular Ubuntu runs GNome (I think).  XUbuntu runs XFCE4.

When I have upgraded my system to Ubuntu 24.10 the issue disappear.
